# Select the column header if cell is formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have pieces of the code figured out, but what I can't quite get is how to parse the column and then select the first row in that column.

The objective is to color the header cell of a column, if the selected cell has a formula. The piece I'm looking for is

```
Sub ColorFormulaHeaders()
Dim oWkbk As Workbook
Dim oWkst As Worksheet
Dim oRng As Range

For Each oRng In Selection.Cells
    If oRng.HasFormula Then
    'Select Column Header
         With Selection
            .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
         End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `With ActiveSheet.Cells(1,oRng.Column)`  In place of `With Selection`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea.  Here is one way to get to the **column header**:

```
Sub ColorFormulaHeaders()
    Dim oWkbk As Workbook
    Dim oWkst As Worksheet
    Dim oRng As Range

    For Each oRng In Selection.Cells
        If oRng.HasFormula Then
             With oRng.EntireColumn.Cells(1).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
             End With
        End If
    Next oRng

End Sub
```

You can use similar technique to get a **row label** for a cell in some row if the label is in column **A** for that cell.

Comment: Love Hungarian `oRange` =)